# Is it worth testing regularly for oxidative stress?

Tags: blood-tests, heart-disease, aging, stress-test, antioxidant

I have read that oxidative stress is associated with neurodegenerative diseases, cardiovascular disease, ageing, cancer, and diabetes. Popular health 'buzz' would suggest consuming antioxidant supplements to ward off these risks, but [research on the overall health benefits of taking these supplements is mixed](http://www.cochrane.org/CD007176/LIVER_antioxidant-supplements-for-prevention-of-mortality-in-healthy-participants-and-patients-with-various-diseases).

In any case, it doesn't seem worthwhile to me to treat a condition you might not have, so is it worth testing oxidative stress levels?

In particular, I am interested in whether:

1. Commonly available oxidative stress tests (FORT and FORD assays?) are reliable enough;
2. It's possible to meaningfully interpret the results of the tests as far as detecting problems;
3. There's something else relevant that I'm missing.